# CSS issue with right transition

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have a piece of code I found for creating an expanding search bar.  It relies on CSS and javascript to run. The demo [found here](http://callmenick.com/lab-demos/3-expanding-search-bar/), has the search bar opening to the right.  I've floated mine right and want it to open on the left.  I just need another set of eyes at this point because I can't find my issue.  The issue is that it opens fine, but it doesn't transition.  It will however, transition while it closes.

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/rEsQ2/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="fix" id="search-bar">
    <div class="search_main fix">
        <form action="http://logans.linkhousedev.net/" method="get" class="searchform" role="search" id="search">
            <div id="label" class="">
                <label id="search-label" for="search-terms">search</label>
            </div>
            <div id="input" class="">
                <input type="search" title="Search for:" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search …" class="search-field" id="search-terms" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#search-bar {
    top: 0;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
#search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
#label {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
#label label {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url("http://callmenick.com/lab-demos/3-expanding-search-bar/img/search.png") 0 0;
    font-size: 0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    text-indent: -9999px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#label label:hover {
    background: url("http://callmenick.com/lab-demos/3-expanding-search-bar/img/search.png") -60px 0
}
#label.active label {
    background: url("http://callmenick.com/lab-demos/3-expanding-search-bar/img/search.png") -60px 0
}
#input {
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 60px;
    top: 0;
    width: 450px;
    z-index: 5;
}
#input input {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -450px;
    width: 430px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #23688b;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    backface-visibility: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    transition: right 0.3s ease 0s;
}
#input input:focus {
    outline: none
}
#input.focus {
    z-index: 20
}
#input.focus input {
    right: 0;
    transition: right 0.3s ease 0.2s;
}
```

**JS**

```
// get vars
var searchEl = $("#input");
var labelEl = $("#label");
// register clicks and toggle classes
labelEl.on("click", function () {
    if (searchEl.hasClass("focus")) {
        searchEl.removeClass("focus");
        labelEl.removeClass("active");
    } else {
        searchEl.addClass("focus");
        labelEl.addClass("active");
    }
});
// register clicks outisde search box, and toggle correct classes
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    var el = $(e.target);
    if (el.attr("id") != "search-terms" && el.attr("id") != "search-label") {
        if (searchEl.hasClass("focus")) {
            searchEl.removeClass("focus");
            labelEl.removeClass("active");
        }
    }
});
```

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated.

Cheers,
Jay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong ID for the larger search bar. This is what you had it look like:

```
<input type="search" title="Search for:" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search …" class="search-field" id="search-terms" />
```

Change the ID from "search-terms" to just "search":

```
<input type="search" title="Search for:" name="s" value="" placeholder="Search …" class="search-field" id="search" />
```

When I did that on jsfiddle it worked flawlessly.

Comment: That works but you shouldn't have two elements on the page with the same id so I would suggest changing the id on the form from 'search' to 'search-form'. Then everything works and you have valid markup.

Comment: Right you are, @ReLeaf. Thanks to both of you for your input.  I'm all set!